# Kotlin: split string from end

Tags: kotlin

I want to split `I_have_a_string` into `I_have_a` and `string`.

Is there a built in function to split from end in Kotlin? The following is what I am doing now:

```
val words = myString.split("_")
val first = words.dropLast(1).joinToString("_")
val second = words.last()
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[substringBeforeLast()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/substring-before-last.html) and [substringAfterLast()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/substring-after-last.html) are Kotlin built in functions very convenient for this case:

```
"I_have_a_string".substringBeforeLast("_") // output: "I_have_a"
"I_have_a_string".substringAfterLast("_") // output: "string"
```